# Succesfull insert into not existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I was creating the SQL Server stored procedure in which I am filling my table with data. The table name is `Person`.

By accident I typed `Persons` instead of `Person` in the procedure. The execution was successful and I could select the inserted data from the `Persons` table.

So the question is, does SQL Server create some hidden new table in the background? I could not find any created new table in the SSMS tables section.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Is there a View called `Persons`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey the question was wrong. I found out that Persons table really existed in my database (i was not creating any tables) so a silly mistake by me. I guess this question can be deleted.

Comment: Or, you can vote your answer! Its alright to solve your own problem. Moral of the story was in fact yes, the proc created a view on a real table. Btw, are they from the same schema? Because specifying explicitly name resolutions is another way to prevent problems. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. However, do keep in mind that if you are using some kind of ORM, table might have been created by it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you wrote your stored procedure.  With the syntax:

SELECT * INTO tblMisTyped FROM TableA

SQL Server does indeed create a temporary table (by design), such that you can later in the same procedure call SELECT * FROM tblMisTyped.  However, this temporary table will be deleted after the procedure has executed.

Comment: The target table is NOT temporary unless the name starts with a # sign.  Tables with a # sign are always temporary for the duration of the connection.  I have used SELECT INTO to create permanent tables many times.

Comment: Sorry you are quite right - I am too used to prefacing with #.  Makes me more certain though, that this is exactly what the OP did.  Particularly since he can now "find" the Persons table